# Does sizeof operator prefer object over type?

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
#include <iostream> 

int C; 

class C { 
  private: 
    int i[2]; 
  public: 
    static int f() { 
        return sizeof(C); 
    } 
}; 

int f() 
{ 
    return sizeof(C); // why the C can't be the class type C.
} 

int main() 
{ 
   std::cout << "C::f() = " <<C::f() << "," 
             << " ::f() = " <<::f() << std::endl; 
}
```

The above code returns: `C::f() = 8, ::f() = 4`

My question is why the identifier `C` inside the global function `f` resolves to the object of type `int` that has name C, instead of the class type `C`? Does `sizeof` have a specific name lookup rule?

**Conclusion** : From what I read in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/1021388, hiding class names by function/object/enumerator names is for compatibility concerns with C. And to avoid this inadvertent hiding, one should `typedef` the class to force compiler errors.

Comment: `sizeof` is called on objects. class type `C` is not an object, it is an implementation of a class. if you want the global `f()` function to call an object of class type `C`, you would need to initialize an instance of it, ie `C C;`

Comment: @RNar "`sizeof` is called on objects" isn't [necessarily true](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof). From cppreference: "\[sizeof\] queries size of the object **or type**."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sizeof` isn't the key to this question. It simply happens to be something that can be used both on type name or a variable name. These rules apply to other uses of identifiers as well.

§9.1 [class.name] (c++ standard draft n3797):

> 2. ...snip... If a class name is declared in a scope where a variable, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated-type-specifier.

There is a class by the name of `C` and a variable by the same name in the global scope. Therefore, the class can be referred to only using an elaborated type specifier (`class C`).

Inside the definition of `C`, however, the first part of that paragraph is relevant:

§9.1 [class.name]:

> 2. A class declaration introduces the class name into the scope where it is declared and hides any class, variable, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope ...snip...

§9 [class]:

> 2. ...snip... The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the injected-class-name ...snip...

So, inside the scope of `class C`, the injected class name hides the `int C` declaration from the outer scope. Therefore you can refer to `C` without elaborated type specifier. To refer to the global `int C`, you could use `::C`

Comment: Great answer! I also found http://stackoverflow.com/a/612476/1021388 a very useful read.

Comment: That answer explains *why* these rules are needed for backwards compatibility with C. Nice find.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question, `sizeof` does not have any special parsing or evaluation rules.

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int C; 

class C { 
public:
    int i[2]; 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
   // compiles fine:
   int x = C;

   // prints 0:
   std::cout << C << "\n";

   // prints something that corresponds to "int"
   // (or even "int" itself):
   std::cout << typeid(C).name() << "\n";
}
```

In all three cases, `C` is taken as the `int` variable and not as the type name.

If you need a clear distinction, you can always use `class C`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int C; 

class C { 
public:
    int i[2]; 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
   // prints something that corresponds to "class C"
   // (or even "class C" itself):
   std::cout << typeid(class C).name() << "\n";

   // prints sizeof(int):
   std::cout << sizeof(C) << "\n";

   // prints sizeof(int) * 2:
   std::cout << sizeof(class C) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: So object names hide user-defined type names (class, union, enum)? What about function names? Do object names also hide functions or the other way? And do function names also hide user-defined type names?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compile this code will give you the answer

```
#include <iostream>

int C;

class C {
    int i[2];
  public: 
    static int f() { 
        return sizeof(C); 
    }
}; 

int f() { 
    return sizeof(C); // why the C can't be the class type C.
} 

int main() {
   C a; // <-- Adding this line generates the error
   std::cout << "C::f() = " <<C::f() << "," 
             << " ::f() = " <<f() << std::endl; 
}
```

---

```
prog.cpp:22:4: error: must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'C' in this scope
   C a;
   ^
   class 
prog.cpp:3:5: note: class 'C' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'C' here
int C; 
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Compiler:

```
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final 246979)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

To get the correct output:

```
int f() { 
    return sizeof(class C);
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Under g++ 4.8.4 with warning enabled, it doesn't generate any error.

Comment: it was compiled on ideone, it doesn't say which compiler it used, but I'm guessing clang. I will clarify in a sec